# Vaadin 14 grid row stripes: How can we reverse the color?

Tags: grid, vaadin, vaadin-flow

We can add a vaadin 14 grid row stripes with the following code.

```
grid.addThemeVariants(GridVariant.LUMO_ROW_STRIPES);
```

But it shows background-image in even row and white in odd row. I can see below css:

```
:host([theme~="row-stripes"]) [part~="row"]:not([odd]) [part~="body cell"],
:host([theme~="row-stripes"]) [part~="row"]:not([odd]) [part~="details-cell"] {
  background-image: linear-gradient(var(--lumo-contrast-5pct), var(--lumo-contrast-5pct));
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

I want to reverse the color, ie. white in even row and background-image in odd row. How can I achieve it? I tried the following css, but it does not work:

```
:host([theme~="row-stripes"]) [part~="row"]:not([even]) [part~="body-cell"],
:host([theme~="row-stripes"]) [part~="row"]:not([even]) [part~="details-cell"] {
  background-image: linear-gradient(var(--lumo-contrast-5pct), var(--lumo-contrast-5pct));
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to override the existing background image on the even rows as well.

So you can do something like this

```css
:host([theme~="row-stripes"]) [part~="row"]:not([odd]) [part~="body-cell"],
:host([theme~="row-stripes"]) [part~="row"]:not([odd]) [part~="details-cell"] {
    background-image: none !important;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

:host([theme~="row-stripes"]) [part~="row"]:not([even]) [part~="body-cell"],
:host([theme~="row-stripes"]) [part~="row"]:not([even]) [part~="details-cell"] {
    background-image: linear-gradient(var(--lumo-contrast-5pct), var(--lumo-contrast-5pct));
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Note that these styles should be placed in a style sheet that targets the shadow dom of the Grid. If you are using the [custom-themeing mechanism](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/customization/custom-theme), then the above styles should be placed under `frontend/themes/<custom-theme-name>/components/vaadin-grid.css`.